# Why do I have to use the name of my type to operate it? [Delphi/Lazarus]

Tags: delphi, record, pascal, lazarus

```
type    
  TSpieler = record
    Name  : string;
    Konto,Position : integer;
    Reihe : boolean;
    Panel : TPanel;
  end;   

var
  PL1, PL2, PL3, PL4, PL5 : TSpieler;

function getPlayer;
begin
  Result := PL1;
end;

procedure FeldKaufen;
var
  TestPlayer: TSpieler;
begin
  TestPlayer := getPlayer; {PL2,PL3,PL4,PL5}
  inc(TestPlayer.Konto); {does not save}
  {inc(PL1.Konto);}      {works just fine with every Player}
end;
```

How can I save `PL1` values after giving them to and editing them from `TestPlayer`?

The problem is I'm getting the name of the player through this `getPlayer` function, and it is good because it makes the whole code a bit cleaner.

Comment: Records are value types. First you copy the contents of `PL1` into `TestPlayer`. Then new values are added to `TestPlayer`. To make these values persist, you must copy them back to `PL1` when the procedure ends.

Comment: But there is problem with the getplayer function, i have no clue how to code an alternative because I use TestPlayer:=getPlayer in a few more procedures to keep the code simple.

Comment: `GetPlayer` will give you a copy of `PL1`. To persist the changes, you could pass the pointer to `PL1` instead.

Comment: I have never used pointers before, where should I build it in?

Comment: What is your **real** problem? Seems you are trying to solve it in the weird manner.

Comment: In this scheme I don't see the necessity to make many users. You can use the only user, using him as var-parameter of procedures (and there are another variants)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to use pointers to the Spieler:

```
type
  PSpieler = ^TSpieler;
  TSpieler = record
    Name: string;
    Konto, Position: integer;
    Reihe: boolean;
    Panel: TPanel;
  end;

var PL1, PL2, PL3, PL4, PL5: TSpieler;

function getPlayer: PSpieler;
begin
  Result := @PL1;
end;

procedure FeldKaufen;
var TestPlayer: PSpieler;
begin
  TestPlayer := getPlayer; {PL2,PL3,PL4,PL5}
  inc(TestPlayer.Konto);   {does not save}
  {inc(PL1.Konto);}        {works just fine with every Player}
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FeldKaufen;
end;
```

Comment: This sounds pretty good, but I get the error: Expression type must be class or record type, got ^TSpieler, as soon as I'm writing       with Testplayer do begin

Comment: @Neubauer, don't use WITH or de-reference the pointer; "with TestPlayer^ do inc(Konto);"

Comment: @Neubauer Please read [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), and possibly act accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

You have not written verifiable code.

Nevertheless, record is [value type](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Structured_Types_(Delphi)#Records_.28traditional.29) (contrary to reference, pointer type (objects)), and assigning one record to another just copies all fields. So changing the second record (copy) does not influence to the first one *(except for special cases like pointer fields of record)*.